# Progress circular vaadin bar applie to a button click

Tags: vaadin

I want to add a circular progress bar to a button click in vaadin spring project using thread not server push but I can't do it have you any idea please?

Comment: I've not used any progress bars, but you may be able to do what you want by settings the poll interval.

Comment: What did you try so far? How exactly should it look like, replacing the button with a GIF loading indicator? Or a real progress bar?

Comment: I have a button: button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) { treatementToDo();}.. I want to add a progress bar which disappear when treatementToDo()  is over.

Comment: You can't do it. You need to use push or polling